# Best way to ask for/about hybrid/remote work?

Tags: telecommute, remote-work

I'm curious what is the best way to ask for/about hybrid remote work when interviewing. I saw something somewhere that suggested asking what is the company's approach to remote/hybrid work but I can not find it again.

Reason I'm asking is I'm in a job that doesn't always feel good/right for me and anything worthwhile is a long commute no matter what I do. Where I live weather is a factor and so is the ability to request working 'at home' (regardless where this is) especially when the weather is not good in the Northeast...

The work I do is mainly IT systems administration, often people hardly talk to me as it is. :)

But places I interview at might be really devoted to having everyone work onsite...what's the best way to 'feel out' this sort of thing??

I realize this is more likely a 2nd round interview question or even wait till after one is hired but it's always good to know.

Comment: It's only worth asking before the interview if the answer would make a difference to whether you attended the interview or not - i.e. is it a deal breaker.

Answer (score 22):

"What is your company's policy on hybrid/remote working?"

Comment: This is I think the most common question asked nowadays from candidates during interviews. Perfectly normal and acceptable.

Comment: I agree with @nicola, I actually find it slightly odd if a candidate _doesn't_ ask this question in an interview now!

Comment: I would add in the follow on question "How would that policy apply to this position?" as the company's policy might be very different from the expectations around this specific role.

Comment: It truly is THAT simple... no idea why people complicate things or have no idea how to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

I mean if for some reason you need to know even if you'll likely consider the job either way (comparing to another job?) and you really think there's potential judgment about something you've revealed with a remote preference, you could be sneaky and say,

"I haven't really looked into how long the commute is likely to be yet. Do you guys have a hybrid policy for bad weather?"

If it were me it would just be the first question I'd ask the first point of contact if it wasn't clear from the job description, but I get that some IT cultures can get surprisingly passive aggressive.